# d3.js nvd3.js — Get y-axis min/max values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3's lineChart model.

I need to force-set the min and max y-axis values relative to the actual ones, e.g.:

chart.lines.forceY([min/1.1,max*1.1]);

How can I get the current min/max y-axis values?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the current domain through `chart.yAxis.scale().domain()`.

Comment: I don't need the domain, but the exact min and max values.

In my case chart.yAxis.scale().domain() returns an array: [0, 1]

Comment: For this, you can use [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_extent) on your data.

Comment: Yes, I can always get the min and max values from the data but it will be a reduntant calculation. I'm asking if there is a way to query the values directly from the chart object as they are already calculated.

Comment: Not unless they're set as the domain of the scale.

Comment: They are not set as the domain.

Comment: Then you'll have to recalculate them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already set the y-axis domain like so:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

y.domain([0, d3.max(yourData)]);
```

you can access the values through `y`.  `y[0]` is the minimum, `y[1]` is the max.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Try also: d3.extent(y.domain()) to return both the lower bound and upper bound values on the y-axis in a simple array.

Comment: Addendum: Once the bounded values are known, you can simply use y(min) or y(max) to get the mapped bounds for your specified range.